How to paginate only one collection in Blade while keeping the other collection static?
I'm working on a Laravel project where I have two collections of jobs: one paginated and one static. Here's the code in my
Note: I want to add 2 different paginator links for featured and jobs

controller:
$jobs = Job::with('employer', 'tags')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(10);

$featuredJobs = Job::with('employer', 'tags')
    ->latest()
    ->where('featured', 1)->latest()
    ->paginate(6);

$tags = Tag::all();

return view('job.index', ['jobs' => $jobs, 'tags' => $tags, 'featuredJobs' => $featuredJobs]);

In my Blade template, I use the paginator to display the paginated jobs:
@foreach ($jobs as $job)
    <!-- Display job details -->
@endforeach

{{ $jobs->links() }}

@foreach ($featuredJobs as $featuredJob)
    <!-- Display featured job details -->
@endforeach
{{ $jobs->links() }}// this for featured job details


Controller
$jobs = Job::with('employer', 'tags')
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(10,['*'], 'jobs');

$futuredJobs = Job::with('employer', 'tags')
    ->where('featured', 1)
    ->latest()
    ->paginate(6,['*'], 'futuredJobs');

View
@foreach ($jobs as $job)
    <!-- Display job details -->
@endforeach

{{ $jobs->appends(['job' => $featuredJob->currentPage()])->links() }}

@foreach ($futuredJobs as $featuredJob)
    <!-- Display featured job details -->
@endforeach
{{ $futuredJobs->appends(['jobs' => $jobs->currentPage()])->links() }}

Note that
Also there are 2 latest() in $futureJobs only use one.
Also compact('jobs','tags','futuredJobs') instead of ['jobs' => $jobs, 'tags' => $tags, 'futuredJobs' => $futuredJobs] can be used while returning variables to view.

I want to use 2 different paginators for those 2 collection, I found that the page name can be set like this
paginate(6, pageName:'featuredPage);

Edited the answer accordingly
